# Implementing BigInt.add()?

Tags: java, implementation, biginteger, bigint, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement my own version of the add() method from the BigInteger class. So far, it works perfectly when given two numbers of the same length, but it fails to compile (index out of bounds) when given two numbers of different lengths. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

If it helps, the output when the two values being added are 10 and 1 is 20.

```
    public BigInt add(BigInt b) {
        int[] ans = new int[value.length];
        int carry=0;

        if(this.lessThan(b))
                for(int i=b.value.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                        int result=this.value[i]+b.value[i]+carry;
                        carry=result/10;
                        result%=10;
                        ans[i]=result;
                }
        else
                for(int i=this.value.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                        int result=this.value[i]+b.value[i]+carry;
                        carry=result/10;
                        result%=10;
                        ans[i]=result;
                }

        String ANSsz=convertArrayToString(ans);
        BigInt Sum = new BigInt(ANSsz);
        return Sum;
    }
```

Comment: Try padding the numbers so they are the same length.

Comment: I would base Bigint on a `int[]` which is used to store 32-bit unsigned values.  This would be much more efficient esp as the whole purpose is to store large numbers.

Comment: You appear to have a problem if the solution is bigger than the two values added. (the `ans` could be value.length+1 in length)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, `ans` length needs to be one larger than the greater of the two `BigInt` lengths. Your `ans` is only ever as big as the object the method is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
   public BigInt add2( BigInt b )
   {
         int answerLength = Math.max( b.value.length, this.value.length ) + 1;
         int[] answer = new int[ answerLength ];

         BigInt bigger = this;
         BigInt smaller = b;
         if( this.lessThan( b ) )
         {
            bigger = b;
            smaller = this;
         }

         // copy the bigger value into answer
         for( int i = bigger.value.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         {
            answer[ i + 1 ] = bigger.value[ i ];
         }

         // add the smaller into the answer
         int carry = 0;
         int lengthOffset = answerLength - smaller.value.length;
         for( int i = smaller.value.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         {
            int result = answer[ i + lengthOffset ] + smaller.value[ i ] + carry;
            carry = result / 10;
            result %= 10;
            answer[ i ] = result;
         }
         answer[ 0 ] = carry;

         String ANSsz = convertArrayToString( answer );
         BigInt Sum = new BigInt( ANSsz );
         return Sum;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an extremely strange solution really. First of all it has the obvious overflow problem (the result of two added ints may not fit into an int itself) and I've got no idea why exactly we'd ever want to divide by 10 for a simple addition of 2 numbers - that's really only necessary for converting a number to a decimal string.

Anyways just think about how many digits the product of two numbers can have. For simplicity we try this in base10, but the generalization is obvious:

A k digit long number is at most `10^k - 1` large. Hence if we have a number with n digits and one with m, the result is at most: `10^n - 1 + 10^m - 1 = 10^n + 10^m - 2`. The largest value we can get is if n == m which is equivalent to 10^n * 2 - 2 which is obviously smaller than 10^(n+1). This means the number has at most one digit more than the larger of the two has (that also holds for base 2 just fine).